# Azure Service Bus Namespace creation is failing with unknown error

Tags: azure, exception, azureservicebus, servicebus

When I am trying to create a Service Bus Namespace in Azure. It is failing with the below exception.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
```

Any help on why this error occurs and how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure its from Azure portal / CLI/ ARM ? Still try adding the resource provider in the subscription level. Go to the subscription--> Resource providers--> add Microsoft.ServiceBus in the list. then i think you should be able to

Comment: Microsoft.ServiceBus is there in that list. Also I am trying to create the namespace from C# code using Microsoft Azure libraries.

Comment: can you share the complete code ?

Comment: Seems to be service principal as a role is not added to the service bus. If true, go to your service bus resource > `Access Control (IAM)` > Add Role assignment > Search your service principal name and add it as a role like `owner`, Save it.

Answer (score 1):

**Please check if the below steps help to work around**:

I have faced similar kind of issue, but the status is Forbidden when creating the Service Bus topic request like `Operation returned an invalid statu code: Forbidden`

Resolve by adding role assignment to this service bus resource in the Azure Portal.
Go to your service bus resource > `Access Control (IAM)` > Add **`Role assignment`** > Search your service principal name and add it as a role like `owner`, Save it.

---

In your case, I believe

> `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'`

There are some causes regarding to similar error in Azure Service Bus Messaging Class like:

- The Operation you're trying to perform does not exist.
- Or the operation giving null in the request body.
- Entity trying to execute the operation against could not be found.

Some troubleshooting steps and recommendations provided by Microsoft Azure in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-exceptions#error-code-not-found).